# Loading txt file into dict, excluding commented rows, but commented row has dict keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have very large text files that I need to load into a python dictionary.  The text file contains numerous rows that describe the data that all start with "#".  I know how to exclude those rows when reading the data into a list ( `if not line.startswith('#')` ), and then then transforming that list into a dictionary ( `data_dict =  map(lambda row:dict(zip(header,row)),data)` ).

The problem that I have is that my code assumes that I already know what the header is and that I can extract the `header` from the text file.  This header can change a little bit from file to file, so I'm hesitant to hard code it as I have it currently.  This header row is included in the commented fields that I'm currently skipping over when reading in the file.

**A sample of the data is provided below:**

```
# Date: 9/26/2014
# Time: 12:04 PM
# Source: XYZ Database
# User: green_bean_4_u
# Headers: tweet_type, user_screeenname, user_id, user_language, event_date
reply;tweeterA;10001;en;9/6/2014m
mention;tweeterB;10002;en;9/6/2014m
retweet;tweeterC;10003;ar;9/6/2014m
mention;tweeterC;10003;ar;9/7/2014m
retweet;tweeterA;10001;en;9/8/2014m
reply;tweeterZ;100026;fr;9/30/2014m
```

The code that I'm using to read the data into a list, excluding commented rows, and transform into a dict, with the provided header:

```
In [2]: data = []

In [3]: for line in open('text_data.txt', 'rb'):
            if not line.startswith('#'):
                data.append(line.rstrip().split(';'))

In [4]: header = ['tweet_type', 'user_screeenname', 'user_id', 'user_language', 'event_date']

In [5]: data_dict =  map(lambda row:dict(zip(header,row)),data)

In [6]: data_dict[0]
Out[6]: {'event_date': '9/6/2014',
          'type': 'reply',
          'user_id': '10001',
          'user_language': 'en',
          'user_screeenname': 'tweeterA'}
```

As I stated, the problem with this is that it assumes that the header, or dict keys, stay the same, and do not change, which is not true.  I would like help figuring out how I can extract the keys from one of the commented rows to use to zip the list into a dictionary.

Comment: Why don't you parse the `# Headers` line to use as the `header` list variable?

Comment: Does the file actually contain the border, or did you make that up just for this post?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget - the file does not contain the border.  I added that to make the sample data more readable.

Comment: @green_bean_4_u, it doesn't make the sample more readable; it just makes it more difficult for others to reproduce. I removed the border from the question.

Comment: It's good practice to include the file _as is_ in your post, so that we know exactly what the input looks like and can give you working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `elif` to your `if` statement that reads in the header:

```
if not line.startswith('#'):
    data.append(line.rstrip().split(';'))
elif line.startswith("# Headers:")
    # remove the "Headers: " part
    after = line.rstrip().split(": ")[1]
    # split around the commas to create the header list
    header = after.split(", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the line with the headers is *uniquely* guaranteed to start with `# Headers`, then your code could be something like this:

```
for line in open('text_data.txt', 'rb'):
    if line.startswith('# Headers'):
        header.append(line.rstrip().split(','))
        header[0] = header[0].replace('# Headers:', '')
    elif not line.startswith('#'):
        data.append(line.rstrip().split(';'))
```

So, you first check to see if it starts with `# Headers`, and if so, capture those items in a separate list, and then, if it wasn't a header, you do the existing comment check and save the items off if not a comment.

Then you have *pair-wise lists* that can be zipped.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **very simple solution**; this version only detects header lines which start with the **exact string** `# Headers:`, among other simplifications, and it raises an exception if it encounters a data line prior to a header line.

I leave a more robust implementation using something like regular expressions or the `csv` module as an exercise ;-)

```
import StringIO

inf = StringIO.StringIO('''
# Date: 9/26/2014
# Time: 12:04 PM
# Source: XYZ Database
# User: green_bean_4_u
# Headers: tweet_type, user_screeenname, user_id, user_language, event_date
reply;tweeterA;10001;en;9/6/2014m
mention;tweeterB;10002;en;9/6/2014m
retweet;tweeterC;10003;ar;9/6/2014m
mention;tweeterC;10003;ar;9/7/2014m
retweet;tweeterA;10001;en;9/8/2014m
reply;tweeterZ;100026;fr;9/30/2014m
''')

headers = None
for line in inf:
    print line
    if line.startswith('# Headers:'):
        header_string = line[10:]
        headers = [x.strip() for x in header_string.split(',')]

    elif line.startswith('#') or not line.strip():
        # skip all other commented or blank lines
        pass

    else:
        if headers is None:
            raise RuntimeError("no header line encountered!")

        d = dict(zip(headers, line.strip().split(';')))
        print d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
headers = []
answer = {}
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith("# Headers:"):
            headers = line.strip().split(":",1)[1].split(',')
            for h in headers:
                if h not in answer:
                    answer[h] = []
        elif not line.startswith("#"):
            vals = line.strip().split(';')
            for h,v in zip(headers, vals):
                answer[h].append(v)
```

Comment: This works fine, but I am not really a fan of `continue` in simple cases like this, since it obscures the fact that the following `if` statements won't get executed. You could simply use `elif` here.

Comment: @DanLenski: changed it. But now, it hides the explicit ignoring of commented out lines

Comment: Right, what I did to avoid hiding that part [in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25735041/20789) was `elif line.startswith("#"): pass` ... `else:`. The Python statement `pass` is just a placeholder empty statement for anywhere that a lack of a statement wouldn't be syntactically valid.